# How can I blur or pixify images in python by using matrixes?

Tags: python, image-processing

I already have a function that converts an image to a matrix, and back. But I was wondering how to manipulate the matrix so that the picture becomes blurry, or pixified?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `scipy`.

To blur use `gaussian_filter` from `scipy.ndimage`.

[Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html)

Please note that blurring may require additional normalization because typically the maximum values go down (are smeared out).

To pixelate use downsampling, for example `decimate` from `scipy.signal`.

[Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.decimate.html)

In case of color images I suggest to apply the blurring or pixelation to each color separately.

Answer (score 0):

To make it blurry filter it using any low-pass filter (mean filter, gaussian filter etc.).